# Being useless at something

Tags: spoken-english

I have seen this sentence somewhere:

> I think I'm useless at sports.

Does it mean that you cannot play any sports? If yes, then can we use "*be useless at*" in general or it is right only in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be useless at sports doesn't mean you literally can't play, it just means you're not any good at it.

This is especially applicable to team sports: some people are so bad that they're useless to the team – the team would have just as good a shot at winning if that person wasn't playing at all, and the team just played a man down.

For individual sports, the phrase makes a little less sense, but you would still be understood if you said you're useless at golf. That's because it's a fairly common phrase that, yes, you can use more generally as well (in non-sports contexts).

Useless at sewing = any shirt you try to make is probably going to fit poorly and fall apart quickly.

Useless at camping = you probably aren't very good at setting up a tent or starting a fire.

Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

The function is:

to be **good**/**perfect**/**bad**/**useless**/**etc** at **something** (**doing something**)

or some other alternatives, which could sometimes be impolite:

> e.g. You're not made for this man! You suck at (playing) volleyball!